# conditional testing with component/cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm looking to do conditional testing in this case
table could exist or not :

```
if (cy.get(#grid).should('not.exist')) {
            //do something
        } else {
            //so something else
        }
```

but seems conditional testing isn't recommended ? any suggestion ?

Comment: "seems conditional testing isn't recommended" Says who? Citation needed. And if you want to do it, why care whether someone else recommends it or not? Presumably you have a _reason_ you want to do it...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Conditional testing is not recommended because it can lead to flakey or incomplete tests. If you have an `if/else` but you never hit the `else`, then you may not be checking all states in your test. Additionally, it can make your tests non-deterministic, and lead to them failing for unanticipated reasons.

That being said, you *can* do conditional testing with Cypress. You'll need to structure it a little differently, as `cy.should()` does not yield a Boolean value. So, we'll have to use some JQuery functions to give us a Boolean we can properly evaluate on in the `if` statement. Unfortunately, doing that condition based on existence is a little tricky. The easiest way to accomplish this is to find an element that is the parent to the element we want to check, and then use [a JQuery command](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to find that child element.

```js
cy.get('#parent').then(($el) => { // get and yield parent element
  if ($el.find('#grid').length) { // check if .find() has any results
    // code if #grid exists
  } else {
    // code if #grid does not exist
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks @agoff, what does '#parent' represents here ? I'm just checking if table exist or not to do some action

Comment: `#parent` would just be an element that contains the `#grid` element. For example, `<span id="parent"><span id="grid"></span></span>`. If the `#grid` element exists on your `body`, this may just be `cy.get('body')`.

Comment: in case of if /else the whole component could not exist at all -means  the whole table could exist or page is empty

Comment: There would be absolutely nothing on the page?

Comment: just button and text field which I'm not going to check, but the whole table will not exist . that's why I'm trying to do actions  when table contains  items and other actions when the table doesn't appear

Comment: Then you could grab the entire body of the HTML and use that as the parent, as I showed in my comment above -> `cy.get('body')`

Answer (score 6):

Just use jQuery (Cypress.$) instead. It does the same as cy.get() but not fails the test when the element is not available.

Use the length property to test - 0 length means nothing found, positive length means one or more.

```js
if (Cypress.$(#grid).length) {
  //do something
} else {
  //so something else
}
```

About recommendation not to use, it's for careless testers. Make sure that the page is **stable** when you use it, that is all parts have loaded (e.g wait for all fetch to complete).

Also remember if running in CI the test moves much slower. Before conditional testing, check loaded elements exist and are visible - and increase timeouts if required.